# Redirect subdirectory to subdomain without domain extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain and a subdomain. My subdomain public folder is published in a subdirectory of the main domain website.
I don't want the subdirectory to be accessed while visiting the main website so I already set up a massive redirect in my main htaccess file.

The redirect works good in the local host that I use for development but of course it doesn't in production because my local host domain extension is `.local` while my remote host extension (published for production) is `.com`.

I don't want to edit my `.htaccess` file every time I have to push changes because I am a human and I do mistakes so I want to avoid misconfigurations that would break my prod website.

I am looking for a possible solution, if there's any, to redirect a subdirectory to a subdomain without mentioning the domain extension so that I can use one `.htaccess` file for prod and dev mode.

The rules I use for dev are these two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-website\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.my-website.local/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

How can I get rid of `.local` so that these rules works both in prod and dev hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a capture group to match and capture `local` or `com` and use a back-reference in target:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?my-website\.(local|com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.my-website.%1/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I've just tried your rules and it redirects to the main domain landing page and not to the subdomain!

Comment: ok. cache disabled. it now redirects but to `blog.my-website./`

Comment: sorry. it seems that cache wasn't really disabled. I had to basically restart my computer and now it works! Thanks a lot!